# Rails 3: How can I reuse code in my next project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-reuse, universal

I want to reuse some controllers, models, stylesheets, images and views in upcoming projects. How is it possible in Rails 3, to have these be standard components, when I create a new project (rails new $project) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract them into Engine or Gems. Structure stylesheets, images in assets. It's not only possible it in fact the standard solution to do. Read some gems to learn this (Devise, kaminari, to name a few).

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would use the same OO principals used in other languages and applications. You can use version control to keep the files in sync if there isolated. However if they are spread about the project you should look into [Rails Engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines). However you are going to run into a lot of headaches if your code is non orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks...it might be Rails engines I should look into, as I understand it by looking at it briefly I can create an engine for each type of project (app, website...), and then bring it in, if I need it in a new project.